# How to save client.pem at a custom location

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to bootstrap a chef client manually using user data following `https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html#bash-user-data` This automatically saves the client.pem file at `/etc/chef`. How to force save at some different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implicitly set `client_key` to your custom location. chef-client detects that the client key file is not present and registers the node, saving the generated key to the file.

relevant code:

- https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/223d9556f1b98e548f26d1ebe4b8eee5f1c98db2/lib/chef/client.rb#L659
- https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/223d9556f1b98e548f26d1ebe4b8eee5f1c98db2/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb#L78

default filename `client.pem` specified in:

- https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/223d9556f1b98e548f26d1ebe4b8eee5f1c98db2/chef-config/lib/chef-config/config.rb#L585-L593

Hope this helps